# how to initialize nsstring with value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, audio

currently im loading my sounds with

```
NSString * strName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"soundpack%ld", (long) (value+1)];
```

to get a value for each sound.

now i want to pull it out of an array. looks like this:

```
NSMutableArray * sounds = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"soundpack1", @"soundpack2", @"soundpack3", @"soundpack4", @"soundpack5", @"soundpack6", @"soundpack7", @"soundpack8", @"soundpack9", nil];
    NSUInteger count = [sounds count];

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        NSInteger nElements = count - i;
        NSInteger n = arc4random_uniform((u_int32_t )nElements) + i;
        [sounds exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
    }
    NSString * strName0 = [sounds objectAtIndex:1];
```

ok, now i have shuffled the sounds., now i want to initialize like before with an specific value.

something like:

```
NSString * strName = [sounds objectAtIndex:%ld, (long) (value+1)];
```

or

```
NSString * strName = [sounds objectAtIndex:@"%ld", (long) (value+1)];
```

didn't work. but i don't know, how to do it now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this line

`NSString * strName = [sounds objectAtIndex:@"%ld", (long) (value+1)];`

to

`NSString * strName = [sounds objectAtIndex:(long) (value+1)];`

Answer (score 0):

Why dont u use the same snippet after shuffling?

```
NSString * strName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"soundpack%ld", (long) (value+1)];
```

Comment: because this snippet is taking the files out of my library, and not out of my array?